# Local variable "item' value not used "unused scope" - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, scope, tooltip

Trying to iterate through a list: `['AEM', 'ATD.B', 'ARX', 'BMO', 'BNS'...]`
Checking for "." (periods) and want to replace them with "-" (dashed lines)

Code:

```
            for ticker in sptsx60:
                if '.' in ticker:
                    ticker = ticker.replace(".", "-")
                else:
                    pass
            print(sptsx60)
```

The third line `ticker = ticker.replace(".", "-")` reads a tooltip "This inspection highlights local variables,parameters or local functions unused in scope" in my PyCharm IDE.

The printed list remains unchanged after the if statement. Was wondering if anyone had more insight regarding the tooltip and how to fix the code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
sptsx60 = ['AEM', 'ATD.B', 'ARX', 'BMO', 'BNS']
sptsx60 = [ticker.replace(".", "-") if '.' in ticker else ticker for ticker in sptsx60 ]

print(sptsx60 )
```

**Output:**

```
['AEM', 'ATD-B', 'ARX', 'BMO', 'BNS']
```

- **Note:** It is not a good idea to modify an element in a list while iterating over it.

Comment: Did not know you could not do that. Thank you!

Comment: Please accept ans(tick symbol next to the ans) if it solved your problem. Thanks.